# Crystal Reports is flipping a picture when I print from my application to pdf

Tags: crystal-reports, sage-300

I've added a logo image to a crystal report, but when I print to pdf from Sage 300, it flips the image so it's upside down.

When I email the report from Sage 300 it is the correct way.

I've tried to Google this, but I can't find anyone else with this same issue.

I'm using a png, but my understanding is Crystal Reports changes this to a bmp file.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image was 32 bit, I changed it to 4 bit and it rendered properly.